# flex builder new projects with syntax errors

Tags: apache-flex, syntax, air

I'm a junior developer and I'm having some problems with my Flex Builder 3. Every time I make a new project, Flex Builder detects syntax errors like:

```
1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbracket before leftbrace. FotoBeheer line 23

1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbracket before public. FotoBeheer line 22

1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before s. DomoticaSystem line 16   

1093: Syntax error. DomoticaSystem line 16
```

Nevertheless, `Fotobeheer` will run, but any other program won't even start. Does anybody have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: When you installed Flex Builder, didn't you see any errors in the log? Did you try to reinstall the Flex Builder? Also, it would be good if you give the project archieve which produce these errors to someone in your company who can test it on his(her) machine to see if this problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is indicitive of syntax problems at or before the first line of error.  Extra brackets or parenthesis are the typical culprit.

Comment: I installed it in a folder which had a name with an '  a stupid mistake! but thx for the help!